# Windows Custom Certificate (certlm.msc) - Default Values

Tags: windows, ssl-certificate, certificate-authority

In windows server 2019, I create custom CSR by invoking certlm.msc, and selecting `Personal -> All Tasks -> Advanced Operations -> Create Custom Request` & then use the Certificate Authority to issue SSL certificates.

Everything works fine, but I need multiple certificates, all have the same `Org-Unit/Org/locality/city/Country` but with different common names. Is there a way to tell windows to retain the previous values (or save them as a template?). currently I have enter all the information each time.

My Certificate authority installation is Standalone & it does not get the "Templates" option that goes with AD installations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `certreq.exe` tool along with INF templates to automate the process. It is not possible to automate in GUI. Specifically, look at [certreq -new](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/certreq_1#certreq--new) command.